# Minimizing $\{0,1\}$-sequence permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, combinatorial-optimization

> **Explanation:** For a given bit sequence $f$, reposition the bits as to minimize $G$ which can be thought of as a measure of how poorly proportional $f$ is to each of its subsequences.

Let $p \in \mathbb N.$ Let $F$ be the function space $\{0,1\}^{\{1\ \ldots\ p\}},$ and $f \in F.$

Let $S = \{\ s\ \big|\ s \in F \land \sum s = \sum f\}$

$$G(f) = \sum_{(n,m)\ :\ 0 \lt n \lt m \leq p}\ \left|\frac{\sum_{n=i}^{m}\ {f_i}}{m-n+1}-\frac{\sum f}{p}\right|$$

> **Question:** Find all $\alpha \in S$ such that $$G(\alpha) = \min_{\beta \in S}\ G(\beta)$$

Disclaimer: I have tried wording this question properly many times. If something is funky or ambiguous, let me know so I can fix it in the future.

**EDIT 11/14/14**

Changed the $G(f)$ measure to be more natural in terms of the explanation.

**EDIT 11/15/14**

Changed the notation.

Comment: I like your question. Can you say anything about what you've tried or what you already know?

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole Thanks. I have tried realizing the sequences as path graphs. I know very little but am very intrigued!

Comment: How high up have you looked by hand? It's roughly clear what the answer "should" look like in general just from solving it up to $p=20$ or so. Also, do you have a particular reason for the weighting you have chosen, rather than, say, multiplying the absolute value by some function of $m-n$ and $p$?

Comment: A noteworthy case is when $p$ is even and $\sum f = \frac{p}{2}$ then $\alpha = 0,1,0\ldots$ or $1,0,1\ldots$.

Comment: I understand what the individual summands are. But this makes the subsequences of length $2$ weak and the subsequences of length $p-1$ strong. Instead of summing $\sum_{n,m}|\Delta|$ you could, for instance sum $\sum_{n,m}\frac{1}{m-n+1}|\Delta|$ so that every subsequence was equally important.

Comment: Maybe we should move this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18408/discussion-between-gabriel-c-drummond-cole-and-green-shape).